# Is there any difference for XPages urls using action=openDocument and action=readDocument?

Tags: xpages

Most times I've seen urls written to open an XPage in read-mode using action=openDocument,  but occasionally, I've see action=readDocument used. Just curious if there are pros/cons in using one vs. the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a difference.  Honestly I never use these URL's anymore myself. So it's really not a big deal very likely.

Keep in mind, you don't need to use these at all of you don't want.  You can pass your own parameter in the URL and then via SSJS access any parameters with the param object.  You can also get the parameters in Java easily enough.

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks David, I was just curious because I'm actually modifying some code Declan wrote awhile back to generate XPages calendars, and it generates links in CSJS with action=  parameters.